# Removing specified character from string in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a string looking like this `",LI,PA,LK";` 
I want to remove the first char, so it looks like `"LI,PA,LK";`

In Java my code to handle this, will look like this:

```
public String returnSubs(String val) {

    int index = val.indexOf(",");       
    String res = val.substring(index+1, val.length());

    return res;
}
```

I want to achieve the exact same thing in SQL, having this query

```
    select patientID, case when liver is not null then 'LI' else '' end 
         || case when kidney_r is not null then ',KR' else '' end
         || case when kidney_l is not null then ',KL' else ''end
         || case when heart is not null then ',HE' else '' end
         || case when liver_domino is not null then ',LI-Dom' else '' end
         || case when lung_r is not null then ',LungR' else '' end
         || case when pancreas is not null then ',PA' else '' end
         || case when liver_split is not null then ',Lsplit' else '' end
         || case when lung_l is not null then ',LungL' else '' end
         || case when intestine is not null then ',Intestine' else '' end
         into organType                       
from offers
where patientID > 1
;
```

Also, the string I get from the query above, could look like `LI, PA, KL,` (notice the comma is at the end, and not the begining)

I see that I can use the `SUBSTRING` and/or INSTR of SQL. But I'm not really sure how. I am creating a procedure where this will be handled

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `LTRIM` here:

```
SELECT
    LTRIM(organTypes, ',') AS col_out
FROM offers;
```

Some databases, such as MySQL, offer functions like `CONCAT_WS` which concatenate with a separator while ensuring that no dangling separators are added to the resulting output.  Oracle does not have this, but `LTRIM` should be sufficient here.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a function [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) that does exactly what you want:

```
trim(leading ',' from col)
```

You can use this in either an `update` or `select`.

Note:  You appear to be storing multiple values in a comma-delimited list.  *That is a very bad way to model data.*  You do not want to overload what strings are by storing multiple values.  Oracle has many better alternatives -- association tables, nested tables, JSON, and XML come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

even this will work:

```
 substr(',LI,PA,LK',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL SERVER:

```
SUBSTRING(VAL,2,LEN(VAL))

VAL--> COLUMN NAME
2--> IT SKIPS 1ST VALUE
LEN-->LENGTH OF THE COLUMN
```